# why location change whenever i start my app from same location

Tags: android, google-maps

hey can anyone tell me while working on google maps why sometimes it happens sometimes i get  my current place and sometimes different one like 900 meters aways from my current location ?? As am beginner so not getting why this happening so . i will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you will need to take a look on how the GPS position is returned in the first place: through your network so the difference in current location and the margin is mostly dependent on network coverage. therefor the lagg could be generated bij lack of connection.

Also the gps location is send through your network device but even when the network coverage is optimized there might still be a small margin between your current position and the indicated position. this has to do with various elements in both connection and server/gps status.

Comment: Well since you now know the problem the answer is quite obvious. the best would be to launch your own GPS satelite and build your own networking. (kidding) just make sure you optimize the weakening elements. your method should be based on the an GPS api wich probably comes with these solutions

Answer (score 0):

Some code explaining how you are setting this up is required, as well as the environment you are in (indoors, out doors stationary, moving etc)

Androids location providers are basically the GPS or the Network (cell towers) and sometimes wifi spots.

You can request to use one of more provider types, and when the location changes the system tells you which provider is giving you the information, and what the accuracy is.

You can also ask Android to give you the "Best" provider by giving it a set of criteria, this has a lot of issues dependent on device though and you might end up with the network when you think you should be getting GPS, so it's best to specifically manage both of them yourselves and not let android/device decide for you.

You can also specify minimum frequency and a geo fence (how far you have moved) before you get an update which will also effect accuracy/power usage if you are moving.

All of these factors have to be taken into account, in general if you are using just GPS and you are stationary then you can get some wonky fixes right out of the gate until accuracy settles down, after which it should progressively get better until it peaks, then you will see accuracy and fixes bounce around a little.

On the other hand if you are driving, and the terrain is changing (hills, buildings, etc) then you need to check the accuracy of the provider and make some best guesses about which to use etc.

If you are inside then signals can degrade, bounce, and do all kinds of interesting things but again the cure is to use the most accurate signal you can get.

If you are letting google maps black box the location stuff then most likely it's environmental or a device "best" provider glitch.

Hope that helps explain things a bit